# Generating a JWT in an Active Directory environment

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, jwt, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API which will run in a very-high security corporate AD environment (no Azure, no Azure AD, which makes Googling for a solution useless).

The API uses JWT auth, and the client will be an Angular 2+ SPA.

What is the easiest way to issue a token?

My initial thought was to set up an authentication endpoint with Windows Authentication that issues the token and populates the claims appropriately.

Is this the best solution?

Or is there another way I can get the JWT token issued without connecting to any external (internet) services?

Comment: Use .net core JwtSecurityToken class?

Comment: Did u arrive at a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Working through this exact thing myself. What we have is a local login and a domain login. The local just authenticates to the DB and the Domain authenticates out to an LDAP. Basically what I am doing is issuing the token based off of a positive authentication regardless if it is the LDAP saying its okay or the DB saying its okay. Here is an example for the DB side of it [.NET Core JWT Authentication](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api). The LDAP logic itself is the same it always has been with DirectoryServices etc. There are a ton of examples on here and elsewhere for that, but to answer your question directly set the token issuance based off of a good authentication to AD instance. Separate the two logic sets and you should be good to go.